# Simpler code to create a cell array of char type with the same prefix + sequential indices?

Tags: arrays, performance, matlab, char, cell

I want to create a cell array with the same prefix + sequential indices, e.g., `{'a1','a2','a3','a4','a5'}`.

The code below can generate the desired output, but I guess there should be much shorter code can do.

```
>> strcat('a',arrayfun(@num2str,1:5,'UniformOutput',false))

ans =

  1×5 cell array

    {'a1'}    {'a2'}    {'a3'}    {'a4'}    {'a5'}
```

It would be greatly appreciated if someone can share ideas to make it in a simpler and more elegant manner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not exactly the same, but if you use the new (not so new any more) string arrays, you can do:

```matlab
"a" + (1:5)
```

This returns:

```
ans = 

  1×5 string array

    "a1"    "a2"    "a3"    "a4"    "a5"
```

In general, the "new" strings are more convenient to use than the old char arrays, for certain things. If you want to manipulate individual characters, it is best to continue using char arrays, but for general string manipulation, and especially manipulation of many strings at once, string arrays provide much better functionality.

Comment: Cool! I think this is the thing I am looking for. Maybe we can use `cellstr("a"+(1:5))` to generate the cell array in turn.' By the way, is it a property of string that it can be concatenated with a number with `+` operator? Where can I find the reference for this use?

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding See the documentation for the `plus` operator: “If one input is a string array, then the other input can be numeric, character, string, or a cell array. In this case, plus converts the non-string input into a string array and then appends corresponding elements of the inputs.” This means the above is equivalent to `"a" + string(1:5)`. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plus.html